# Is there any problem with Rounding off to 6 digits?

Tags: python, rounding, precision, numerical-methods

I tried the following code to find the root of an equation using incremental search technique. When I set the precision to 5 or 7 digits, the code worked perfectly. But when I set the precision to 6 digits, the code is unable to give the proper value What should I do in this case. The code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl
import prettytable as PT

func_input=input("Function i/p (in numpy notation): ")
fn = eval("lambda x:" + func_input)
## (667.38/x)*(1-np.exp((-0.146843)*x))-40
print ("Function is: ",func_input)
p=int(input("Precision: "))

print("Refer to the graph of the function for the start value")
x1=float(input("Start From: "))

i=0
m=x1
while (m<=x1+4.0):
    m=x1+i*(10**(-p))
    y=round(fn(m),p)
    if (y==0):
        break
    i+=1

print("The root is: ",m)
```

I got the following output for various precision values:

```
Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 22:39:24) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
= RESTART: C:/Users/3D/Desktop/Rushikesh/Python Programs/Roots of Equation/Bracketing Methods/05_Incremental Search.py
Function i/p (in numpy notation): (667.38/x)*(1-np.exp((-0.146843)*x))-40
Function is:  (667.38/x)*(1-np.exp((-0.146843)*x))-40
Precision: 5
Refer to the graph of the function for the start value
Start From: 14.5
The root is:  14.78021
>>> 
= RESTART: C:/Users/3D/Desktop/Rushikesh/Python Programs/Roots of Equation/Bracketing Methods/05_Incremental Search.py
Function i/p (in numpy notation): (667.38/x)*(1-np.exp((-0.146843)*x))-40
Function is:  (667.38/x)*(1-np.exp((-0.146843)*x))-40
Precision: 7
Refer to the graph of the function for the start value
Start From: 14.5
The root is:  14.7802086
>>> 
= RESTART: C:/Users/3D/Desktop/Rushikesh/Python Programs/Roots of Equation/Bracketing Methods/05_Incremental Search.py
Function i/p (in numpy notation): (667.38/x)*(1-np.exp((-0.146843)*x))-40
Function is:  (667.38/x)*(1-np.exp((-0.146843)*x))-40
Precision: 6
Refer to the graph of the function for the start value
Start From: 14.5
The root is:  18.500001
>>>
```

Comment: In what way is the scale of the function value related to the scale of the function argument? If you multiply the function by 1000, the root does not change, but your method has a radically different behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the rounding is causing the routine to skip the termination case (so that *y* goes just under zero and just over zero without actually hitting zero).

Suggest replacing the `y == 0` test with `math.close()` or just returning the *x* for the lowest magnitude *y* that is found (i.e. the closest to zero).

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Small mistake: it's `math.isclose`. Could not edit it because SO doesn't want a 2-char fix and I didn't think further messing up with the comment just to get a small fix in would be useful. Incidentally and to note that this is not specifically an issue with rounding to 6 digits, the issue also occurs (for similar reasons) at n=8, and probably others.

Comment: @Masklinn That makes sense.  Regardless of the exact precision, you will periodically get a round-down below zero, followed by a round-up above zero, and never hit zero exactly.